# MySQL: Query for getting MAX value after filtering columns

Tags: mysql, sorting, max

I have the following table

```
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| date       | time  | custom_id  | Number    |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 01/02/2014 | 01:00 | ABC123     | 15        |
| 01/06/2014 | 02:00 | ABC123     | 11        |
| 01/06/2014 | 00:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/06/2014 | 01:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/07/2014 | 01:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/08/2014 | 00:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/09/2014 | 14:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/10/2014 | 22:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/10/2014 | 23:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/12/2014 | 18:30 | HEY567     | 28        |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I:

1. **SELECT** a date range from **01/06/2014** starting at Time **00:00** UNTIL **01/10/2014** at **23:00**
2. Order from **MAX** to **MIN** the Column named **Number** for Each day
3. Also sort the table based on the **custom_id** column

I'd like it to look similar to this in the end:

```
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| date       | time  | custom_id  | Number    |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 01/06/2014 | 01:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/06/2014 | 00:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/06/2014 | 02:00 | ABC123     | 11        |
| 01/07/2014 | 01:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/08/2014 | 00:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/09/2014 | 14:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
| 01/10/2014 | 22:00 | HEY567     | 28        |
| 01/10/2014 | 23:00 | ABC123     | 17        |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I accomplish this with a MySQL Query?

Thanks in advance

SQLFiddle with a query I did earlier: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d2b9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m not sure if your column 'time' has data like '23:30', and this may works:

```
SELECT date, time, custom_id, Number
FROM traffic
WHERE CONCAT(date, " ", time) BETWEEN "01/06/2014 00:00" AND "01/10/2014 23:00"
ORDER BY date, CAST(Number as SIGNED) DESC, custom_id
```

Combines 'date' and 'time' by `CONCAT`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f57b7/8

Comment: thanks a lot, how can I modify your script so that I just keep the MAX value for **each day** for each **custom_id**

Comment: You mean MAX Number for each day for each custom_id?

Comment: Yes the MAX Number for each custom_id, FOR each day. A bit difficult to explain :-) thanks alot for your help. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MySQL query that will look for dates between 1/6/2014 and 1/10/2014 then order by the number column in descending order and the custom_id in ascending order

```
SELECT date, MIN(time) as time, custom_id, SUM(Number) as numbersum
FROM traffic
WHERE time between "00:00" and "23:00" and date between "01/06/2014" and "01/10/2014"
GROUP BY date, custom_id, HOUR(time)
ORDER BY numbersum desc, custom_id
```

Comment: It doesn't need to.  He said it was between 0:00 and 23:00, which is the entire day...soo

Comment: but i'll include that